# Running multiple Spring boot executable jars on self contained server as Linux services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have deployed my first spring boot web application executable jar in self contained tomcat server successfully and accessing it on port 8080 but when I deployed my second app on different port using  init.d on port 42000 I am unable to access it. I have looked the log in /var/log the application starts successfully without any errors. What would be the causes for my problem?

Comment: A firewall blocking access to port 42000?

Comment: have you added `server.port=42000` property in application.properties file ? what is response when you try to access your web application ?

Comment: yes, I have added the server.port property. the log stays at this line when I tried to access it.2017-11-07 07:15:18.106  INFO 18236 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 42000 (http)
2017-11-07 07:15:18.118  INFO 18236 --- [           main] com.FromExcelToDBMSApplication           : Started FromExcelToDBMSApplication in 9.864 seconds (JVM running for 10.56)